# Vue & Native messaging

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chrome-native-messaging

I've created a simple test webpage that sends data and receives data to/from a native application using the example in:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging

[image]

The web is created using Vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
        Enter Message: <input id="message"></input>
        <button id="ping" type="button">Ping!</button><br/>
        Output message: <span id="output"></span>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {

}
</script>
```

The plugin background.js

```
/*
On startup, connect to the "ping_pong" app.
*/
var port = browser.runtime.connectNative("ping_pong");

/*
Listen for messages from the app.
*/

port.onMessage.addListener((response) => {
  console.log("bg Received: " + response);

  browser.tabs.query({
    currentWindow: true,
    active: true
  }).then(sendMessageToTabs.bind(null, response))


});

browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(notify);

function notify(message) {
  console.log("bg Sending:  ping" + message);
  port.postMessage("Received and returned message: " + message);
}



function sendMessageToTabs(message, tabs ) {
    console.log("bs message:");
    console.log(message);
    console.log("bs tabs:");
    console.log(tabs);
  for (let tab of tabs) {
    browser.tabs.sendMessage(
      tab.id,
      {message}
    );
  }
}
```

and contentScript.js

```
console.log("Content script found!");

if (document.getElementById("ping")) {
    document.getElementById("ping").addEventListener("click", notifyExtension);
}

function notifyExtension(e) {
    console.log("cs Clicked!");
    console.log("cs sending " + document.getElementById("message").value);
    browser.runtime.sendMessage(document.getElementById("message").value);
}

browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(notify);

function notify(message) {
    console.log("cs Received; ");
    console.log(message);
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = message.message;
}
```

My question is, what would we the way to make Vue receive the returned data to be able to use it, process, etc... I mean, to save it in a vue data variable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your Vue component, use a computed property to return the value of the message, whereas computed properties watch for changes and update accordingly.

For example:

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ message }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
  computed: {
    message() {
      return window.message // or whatever the variable is
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: i think changes are only detected for data properties or props of the component

Comment: Computed properties are cached but change when their dependencies change.